# calling a value from a nested array in php outputs the letter "u"?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to dump an array from a separate JSON file. When I dump the array, it returns "NULL".

The code below is for turning the JSON array into a PHP array, then dumps it into the page.

`$rightcont = file_get_contents("./pass.json");`
`var_dump(json_decode($rightcont));`

The pass.json file includes:

`{"user": ["username":"foo","password":"bar"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things (working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee8ebad038b540e92eba72b5c66e67b5acd6f3f7)):

- your json is [invalid](https://jsonlint.com/) - use this: `{"user": {"username":"foo","password":"bar" }}`
- use `json_decode($rightcont, true)` to get the array ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) more details)